# how to assert if a method has been called using nunit

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

is it possible to assert whether a method has been called?  I'm testing the following method and I want to assert that the _tokenManager.GetToken() has been called.  I just want to know if the method has been called as the method does not return a value.  I am using Moq.

Thanks,

**Code snippet**

```
public void Subscribe(string code, string emailAddress, string columnKey)
{
    // Request authentication token
    var token = _tokenManager.GetToken(code, false);

    if (!_tokenValidator.Validate(token))
    {
        // Token has expired or invalid - refresh the token 
        token = _tokenManager.GetToken(code, true);
    }

    // Subscribe email
    _silverpopRepository.Subscribe(token.AccessToken, emailAddress, columnKey);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at MOQ or other mocking frameworks? I believe NUnit has its own, but I am not familiar with it?

Comment: I've updated my question, I'm using Moq.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should mock `TokenManager` and `TokenValidator`, and then create two unit test cases:

- Case 1: **token is validated** and `GetToken` is called exactly once
- Case 2: **token is not validated** and `GetToken` is called exactly twice

Case 1:

```
[Test]
public void Subscribe_TokenIsValidated_GetTokenIsCalledOnce()
{
    // Arrange:
    var tokenManagerMock = Mock.Of<TokenManager>();

    var tokenValidatorMock = Mock.Of<TokenValidator>(x =>
        x.Validate(It.IsAny<Token>()) == true);

    var subscriber = new Subscriber
    {
        TokenManager = tokenManagerMock,
        TokenValidator = tokenValidatorMock
    };

    // Act:
    subscriber.Subscribe(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<string>());

    // Assert:
    Mock.Get(tokenManagerMock).Verify(x =>
        x.GetToken(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>()), Times.Once);
}
```

Case 2:

```
[Test]
public void Subscribe_TokenIsExpiredOrInvalid_GetTokenIsCalledTwice()
{
    // Arrange:
    var tokenManagerMock = Mock.Of<TokenManager>();

    var tokenValidatorMock = Mock.Of<TokenValidator>(x =>
        x.Validate(It.IsAny<Token>()) == false);

    var subscriber = new Subscriber
    {
        TokenManager = tokenManagerMock,
        TokenValidator = tokenValidatorMock
    };

    // Act:
    subscriber.Subscribe(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<string>());

    // Assert:
    Mock.Get(tokenManagerMock).Verify(x =>
        x.GetToken(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>()), Times.Exactly(2));
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can create an unit test without mocking `TokenValidator` and verify if `GetToken()` has been called at least once. However, creating two cases as in the first example is preferred as we are testing all code paths.

```
// Arrange:
var tokenManagerMock = Mock.Of<TokenManager>();
var subscriber = new Subscriber {TokenManager = tokenManagerMock};

// Act:
subscriber.Subscribe(It.IsAny<string>(),
    It.IsAny<string>(),
    It.IsAny<string>());

// Assert:
Mock.Get(tokenManagerMock).Verify(x =>
        x.GetToken(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>()), Times.AtLeastOnce);
```

---

Read more about verification in Moq at:

- [Moq quick start](https://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) at official website
- [Verifying the Number of Calls to a Mocked Method](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/MoqTimes.aspx) at BlackWasp

Answer (score 9):

You can verify using MOQ using the Verify method. Like this:

```
var tokenManagerMock = new Mock<ITokenManager>();
var sut = new WhateverItIsCalled(tokenManagerMock.Object);
sut.Subscribe("ssss", "example@example.com", "XXX");
tokenManagerMock.Verify(m => m.GetToken(It.Is<string>(c => c == "ssss", It.Is<bool>(x => x == false)), Times.Once);
```

You need to be able to pass the token manager into your system under test somehow. Usually via the ctor or maybe a property.

I would suggest you use something like AutoFixture to remove the ugliness that is "ssss" and make things a bit more DRY.

You may need to make the token manager mock return something appropriate too that will pass the validation. Something like this:

```
var tokenManagerMock = new Mock<ITokenManager>();
tokenManagerMock.Setup(m => m.GetToken(It.Is<string>(x => x == "ssss", It.IsAny<bool>()).Returns("XXXXXX");
```

Comment: Actually, unless it is necessary I would suggest using It.IsAny<string>()