# NUnit - Testing that a Method was Called

Tags: c#, nunit

How do I test the following code?

```
public void CreateRentalIfNecessary(int? rentalId)
{
  if (rentalId.HasValue) { CreateRental(rentalId.Value); }
}
```

I need to write a simple unit test to verify that `CreateRental` is called when the `rentalId` is not `null`. How do I test this?

Then answer here seems way too complicated: [how to assert if a method has been called using nunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331947/how-to-assert-if-a-method-has-been-called-using-nunit)

Comment: Normally, you would test that the method was called by checking if `CreateRental` did what it was supposed to do, for example, adding a new rental to your database or mock database.

Comment: Unit testing is hard. I'd say the article you referenced was spot on. There is no built mechanism to do this with nUnit alone. You would need to use some kind of mocking framework in conjunction with writing your code with testing in mind, i.e. following SOLID principles.

Comment: Several thoughts come to mind. If CreateRental references some object inserted via dependency injection, you could instantiate the object using Moq and use Moq's Verify method to verify the method was/was not called. Or use Unity Interception to implement method enter/exit tracing and assert it that way. Or implement method enter/exit logging and verify by reading the log file. Hope this helps.

Comment: @MitchStewart Create rental is in the same service class as the method under test. We ARE using Moq, so that's available to me.

Comment: If CreateRental has an external dependency, I'd inject a Moq'd up version of the dependency, which would come with the dependency.Verify(m => m.Foo(), Times.Once()/Times.Never()) method.

Comment: You need to show the code for `CreateRental()` if you want us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Taking the example at face value, you are trying to simultaneously test two methods of the same object, `CreateRentalIfNecessary` and `CreateRental`. Since they are both in the same object, you can't use a mock. This leads me to several alternative conclusions...

1. One of the methods may be unneeded. Do you really want to create a method when it's **not** necessary? Perhaps you can just remove the ...IfNecessary variant and always check for necessity in `CreateRental`. Whether this is possible, of course, depends on how the methods are being called.
2. As a variant, simply have clients make the test to see if the call is needed.
3. If both are **really** needed, I presume you are testing `CreateRental`. In that case, you should be able to reuse the same test cases for `CreateRentalIfNeeded`.

My preference would be to go for something like (1). It's possible that your tests are telling you to refactor the SUT.

Comment: I had the if statement in an API controller method. Our architect asked me to test the entire controller to see if `CreateRental` is called - seemed stupid to me so I tried to move it out into separate method for testing. Now I am in this dilemma. Anyway, ty for all the options!